# Unable to boot from USB Drive UEFI usb not listed in boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, uefi

Recently I decided to start using Ubuntu, after trying it on a VM I decided to dual boot alongside Windows 10. Windows 10 runs on my Samsung 850 SSD, I decided to partition my HDD and run Ubuntu on there instead.
After a while I decided to get another SSD purely for Ubuntu. Naively I just  deleted the partition on the HDD containing Ubuntu thinking that would simply remove it altogether. Of course, Ubuntu is still listed in my Boot menu.
The problem I am now having is that I am unable to boot the ISO of Ubuntu from the USB drive I am using.
In the boot menu I do not get the option to boot from "UEFI USB" or anything along those lines. Instead the only relevant option is simply liste d as "Sandisk".
I have tried changed the boot orders and disabling secure boot. I have used Etcher to flash the drive. I now have no idea what to do. I didn't have these issues before when I dual booted via the partitioned drive, however I used a different USB drive which is no longer in my possession.

Any help with this issue will be massivel appreciated!

many thanks

Comment: Welcome! This sound like a problem with your usb, or some BIOS/UEFI configuration. That your BIOS/UEFI does not recognize it has nothing to do with the OSs you have installed, or how you created the usb.

Comment: UNetbootin, Rufus and mkusb all make drives that boot BIOS or UEFI, However balenaEtcher usually works for me also. mkusb seems the most reliable, but this may just be personal preference. Just about every bootable USB problem can be found here > https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot